Google Cloud Run: Python flask api keeps timing out
I am running a Flask app in Cloud Run, as an API service. When Cloud Run is bringing up a new instance to service an API, the Flask App is unable to service the API. From the Cloud Run console logs, it looks like the App was successfully brought up.
Here is the Cloud Run console log snippet:
2024-04-03 19:30:57.734 PDT  [2024-04-04 02:30:57 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2024-04-03 19:30:57.735 PDT  [2024-04-04 02:30:57 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
2024-04-03 19:30:57.735 PDT  [2024-04-04 02:30:57 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2024-04-03 19:30:57.757 PDT  [2024-04-04 02:30:57 +0000] [2] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2
2024-04-03 19:30:58.672 PDT  APP Loading: 0.8971238136291504 sec
2024-04-03 19:31:04.226 PDT  [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /home/nltk_data...
2024-04-03 19:31:04.516 PDT  [nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
2024-04-03 19:31:05.829 PDT  [nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /home/nltk_data...
2024-04-03 19:31:05.908 PDT  [nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/stopwords.zip.
2024-04-03 19:31:08.050 PDT  STARTUP HTTP probe succeeded after 3 attempts for container "backend-1" on path "/".
2024-04-03 19:31:54.527 PDT  GET  504  713 B  60 s  Chrome 123 https://backend-uw.a.run.app/reports?user=12345 

Here is the code snippet of my main.py
import time
__init_time = time.time()

import json
import logging
import os
import shutil
from threading import Thread
import uuid

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import abort
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Response
from flask_cors import CORS
from lazy_import import lazy_class

# Lazy loading modules that take longer to import,
# to improve backend app load latency
GptController = lazy_class(
    'controls.gpt_controller.GptController')
DocumentsController = lazy_class(
    'controls.documents_controller.DocumentsController')
FirestoreController = lazy_class(
    'controls.firestore_controller.FirestoreController')
UserController = lazy_class(
    'controls.user_controller.UserController')
Utilities = lazy_class(
    'utils.utilities.Utilities')

logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('httpx').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

TEMP_FOLDER = 'temp'

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

# create the folders when setting up your app
os.makedirs(
    os.path.join(app.instance_path, TEMP_FOLDER),
    exist_ok=True)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    """Entry-point route for Cloud Run Startup HealthCheck"""
    __time = time.time()
    while (time.time()-__time) < 10:
        try:
            if FirestoreController().firestore_client:
                return "<h1>App Alive</h1>"
        except Exception as _:
            pass
        time.sleep(0.5)
    abort(500, 'Server not ready')

@app.route("/reports", methods=["GET"])
def report_operations():
    """
    Entry-point function to different API operations on 'report'
    """
    return { "status": "success" }


print(f'APP Loading: {time.time() - __init_time} sec')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(
        debug=True,
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080))
    )

Here is the Docker file for the container
FROM python:3.9

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install Python dependencies.
RUN python -m venv xplor-env
ENV PATH="xplor-env/bin:$PATH"
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app



Brought the app load latency down to ~1 second, using lazy imports
Added an HTTP Startup Health check probe to the '/' route on the app


What are you doing in the /reports that take more than 60s? Did you try your container locally?

@guillaumeblaquiere the '60s' is the default Request Timeout I have set for the service in Cloud Run configuration. I am observing the issue not 100%, but more like 90% of the time. So I am guessing somehow the request is not even reaching the end-point whenever the container/app gets into this state
